# Are there any API's for Amazon Web Services PRICING?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Are there any API's that have up-to-date pricing on Amazon Web Services? Something that can be queried, for example, for the latest price S3 for a given region, or EC2, etc.

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334035/get-ec2-pricing-programmatically

Comment: AWS has a Price List API now https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/

Comment: Use the CLI... example: `aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history --instance-types m1.xlarge --product-description "Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)" --start-time 2016-10-31T03:00:00 --end-time 2016-10-31T03:16:00 --query 'SpotPriceHistory[*].[Timestamp,SpotPrice]'` see the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-spot-price-history.html)

Answer (score 38):

**UPDATE:**

AWS has pricing API nowadays: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/

**Original answer:**

This is something I have asked for (via AWS evangelists and surveys) previously, but hasn't been forthcoming. I guess the AWS folks have more interesting innovations on their horizon.

As pointed out by @brokenbeatnik, there is an API for spot-price history. API docs here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeSpotPriceHistory.html

I find it odd that the spot-price history has an *official* API, but that they didn't do this for on-demand services at the same time. Anyway, to answer the question, **yes you can query the *advertised* AWS pricing**...

The best I can come up with is from examining the (client-side) source of the various services' pricing pages. Therein you'll find that the tables are built in JS and populated with JSON data, data that you can GET yourself. E.g.:

- http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/pricing-on-demand-instances.json
- http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/pricing-storage.json

That's only half the battle though, next you have to pick apart the object format to get at the values you want, e.g., in Python this gets the Hi-CPU On-Demand Extra-Large Linux Instance pricing for Virginia:

```
>>> import json
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/pricing-on-demand-instances.json')
>>> pricejson = response.read()
>>> pricing = json.loads(pricejson)
>>> pricing['config']['regions'][0]['instanceTypes'][3]['sizes'][1]['valueColumns'][0]['prices']['USD']
u'0.68'
```

Disclaimer: Obviously this is not an AWS sanctioned API and as such I wouldn't recommend expecting stability of the data format or even continued existence of the source. But it's there, and it beats transcribing the pricing data into static config/source files!

Comment: It's also worth noting a caveat with reading spot price history from the API - it will only show changes between your start+end time. Some instance types aren't supported in certain availability zones (and detecting this is quite hard since if you ask for the last 24 hours of spot price data an unchanged price would look like an unsupported instance type in that region (or vice versa)

Comment: Note that as of April 2014, those URLs are deprecated and the pricing info is outdated. They're now at http://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/ec2/linux-od.min.js and http://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/s3/pricing-storage-s3.min.js. If you look in the source of any pricing page and search for "json" you'll find the appropriate links.

Comment: @TimDorr can you edit the post, or post your answer if the above is now outdated?

Comment: AWS has a Price List API now https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/

Answer (score 14):

For the people who wanted to use the data from the amazon api who uses things like "t1.micro" here is a translation array

```
type_translation = {
    'm1.small' : ['stdODI', 'sm'],
    'm1.medium' : ['stdODI', 'med'],
    'm1.large' : ['stdODI', 'lg'],
    'm1.xlarge' : ['stdODI', 'xl'],
    't1.micro' : ['uODI', 'u'],
    'm2.xlarge' : ['hiMemODI', 'xl'],
    'm2.2xlarge' : ['hiMemODI', 'xxl'],
    'm2.4xlarge' : ['hiMemODI', 'xxxxl'],
    'c1.medium' : ['hiCPUODI', 'med'],
    'c1.xlarge' : ['hiCPUODI', 'xl'],
    'cc1.4xlarge' : ['clusterComputeI', 'xxxxl'],
    'cc2.8xlarge' : ['clusterComputeI', 'xxxxxxxxl'],
    'cg1.4xlarge' : ['clusterGPUI', 'xxxxl'],
    'hi1.4xlarge' : ['hiIoODI', 'xxxx1']
}
region_translation = {
    'us-east-1' : 'us-east',
    'us-west-2' : 'us-west-2',
    'us-west-1' : 'us-west',
    'eu-west-1' : 'eu-ireland',
    'ap-southeast-1' : 'apac-sin',
    'ap-northeast-1' : 'apac-tokyo',
    'sa-east-1' : 'sa-east-1'
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I've create a quick & dirty API in Python for accessing the pricing data in those JSON files and converting it to the relevant values (the right translations and the right instance types).

You can get the code here: https://github.com/erans/ec2instancespricing

And read a bit more about it here: http://forecastcloudy.net/2012/04/03/quick-dirty-api-for-accessing-amazon-web-services-aws-ec2-pricing-data/

You can use this file as a module and call the functions to get a Python dictionary with the results, or you can use it as a command line tool to get the output is a human readable table, JSON or CSV to use in combination with other command line tools.

Comment: Very nice but i noted it doesnt include the previous generation instances like t1.micro - is there another .js file that contains those prices ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's an API that covers general current prices for the standard services.  However, for EC2 in particular, you can see spot price history so that you don't have to guess what the market price for a spot instance is.  More on this is available at:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-spot-instances-history.html

Comment: i wasn't able to find anything for base pricing, however deltacloud is a very interesting project for cross-cloud information and management http://deltacloud.org/

Comment: I also did not see a general API for pricing. The closest I found was the spot price history that brokenbeatnik described.

Answer (score 1):

I too needed an API to retrieve AWS pricing. I was surprised to find nothing especially given the large number of APIs available for AWS resources.

My preferred language is Ruby so I wrote a Gem to called [AWSCosts](https://github.com/srbartlett/awscosts) that provides programmatic access to AWS pricing.

Here is an example of how to find the on demand price for a m1.medium Linux  instance.

> AWSCosts.region('us-east-1').ec2.on_demand(:linux).price('m1.medium')

Answer (score 1):

For those who need the comprehensive AWS instance pricing data (EC2, RDS, ElastiCache and Redshift), here is the Python module grown from the one suggested above by [Eran Sandler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180582/eran-sandler):

https://github.com/ilia-semenov/awspricingfull

It contains previous generation instances as well as current generation ones (including newest d2 family), reserved and on-demand pricing. JSON, Table and CSV formats available.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/3303769) of forward and reverse names in Yaml should anyone need them for Rails, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick & dirty, but with a conversion to a more convenient final data format

```
 class CostsAmazon(object):
    '''Class for general info on the Amazon EC2 compute cloud.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        '''Fetch a bunch of instance cost data from Amazon and convert it
        into the following form (as self.table):

        table['us-east']['linux']['m1']['small']['light']['ondemand']['USD']
        '''
        #
        #    tables_raw['ondemand']['config']['regions'
        #        ][0]['instanceTypes'][0]['sizes'][0]['valueColumns'][0
        #        ]['prices']['USD']
        #
        # structure of tables_raw:
        # ┃
        # ┗━━[key]
        #    ┣━━['use']        # an input 3 x ∈ { 'light', 'medium', ... }
        #    ┣━━['os']         # an input 2 x ∈ { 'linux', 'mswin' }
        #    ┣━━['scheduling'] # an input
        #    ┣━━['uri']        # an input (see dict above)
        #    ┃                 # the core output from Amazon follows
        #    ┣━━['vers'] == 0.01
        #    ┗━━['config']:
        #   *   ┣━━['regions']: 7 x
        #       ┃  ┣━━['region'] == ∈ { 'us-east', ... }
        #   *   ┃  ┗━━['instanceTypes']: 7 x
        #       ┃     ┣━━['type']: 'stdODI'
        #   *   ┃     ┗━━['sizes']: 4 x
        #       ┃        ┗━━['valueColumns']
        #       ┃           ┣━━['size']: 'sm'
        #   *   ┃           ┗━━['valueColumns']: 2 x
        #       ┃              ┣━━['name']: ~ 'linux'
        #       ┃              ┗━━['prices']
        #       ┃                 ┗━━['USD']: ~ '0.080'
        #       ┣━━['rate']: ~ 'perhr'
        #       ┣━━['currencies']: ∈ { 'USD', ... }
        #       ┗━━['valueColumns']: [ 'linux', 'mswin' ]
        #
        # The valueColumns thing is weird, it looks like they're trying
        #   to constrain actual data to leaf nodes only, which is a little
        #   bit of a conceit since they have lists in several levels.  So
        #   we can obtain the *much* more readable:
        #
        #     tables['regions']['us-east']['m1']['linux']['ondemand'
        #         ]['small']['light']['USD']
        #
        # structure of the reworked tables:
        # ┃
        # ┗━━[<region>]: 7 x ∈ { 'us-east', ... }
        #    ┗━━[<os>]: 2 x ∈ { 'linux', 'mswin' }  # oses
        #       ┗━━[<type>]: 7 x ∈ { 'm1', ... }
        #          ┗━━[<scheduling>]: 2 x ∈ { 'ondemand', 'reserved' }
        #             ┗━━[<size>]: 4 x ∈ { 'small', ... }
        #                ┗━━[<use>]: 3 x ∈ { 'light', 'medium', ... }
        #                   ┗━━[<currency>]: ∈ { 'USD', ... }
        #                      ┗━━> ~ '0.080' or None
        uri_base = 'http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing'
        tables_raw = {
            'ondemand': {'scheduling': 'ondemand',
                         'uri': '/pricing-on-demand-instances.json',
                         'os': 'linux', 'use': 'light'},
            'reserved-light-linux':  {
                'scheduling': 'ondemand',
                'uri': 'ri-light-linux.json', 'os': 'linux', 'use': 'light'},
            'reserved-light-mswin': {
                'scheduling': 'ondemand',
                'uri': 'ri-light-mswin.json', 'os': 'mswin', 'use': 'light'},
            'reserved-medium-linux': {
                'scheduling': 'ondemand',
                'uri': 'ri-medium-linux.json', 'os': 'linux', 'use': 'medium'},
            'reserved-medium-mswin': {
                'scheduling': 'ondemand',
                'uri': 'ri-medium-mswin.json', 'os': 'mswin', 'use': 'medium'},
            'reserved-heavy-linux': {
                'scheduling': 'ondemand',
                'uri': 'ri-heavy-linux.json', 'os': 'linux', 'use': 'heavy'},
            'reserved-heavy-mswin': {
                'scheduling': 'ondemand',
                'uri': 'ri-heavy-mswin.json', 'os': 'mswin', 'use': 'heavy'},
            }
        for key in tables_raw:
            # expand to full URIs
            tables_raw[key]['uri'] = (
                '%s/%s'% (uri_base, tables_raw[key]['uri']))
            # fetch the data from Amazon
            link = urllib2.urlopen(tables_raw[key]['uri'])
            # adds keys: 'vers' 'config'
            tables_raw[key].update(json.loads(link.read()))
            link.close()
            # canonicalize the types - the default is pretty annoying.
            #
        self.currencies = set()
        self.regions = set()
        self.types = set()
        self.intervals = set()
        self.oses = set()
        self.sizes = set()
        self.schedulings = set()
        self.uses = set()

        self.footnotes = {}
        self.typesizes = {}   # self.typesizes['m1.small'] = [<region>...]
        self.table = {}

        # grovel through Amazon's tables_raw and convert to something orderly:
        for key in tables_raw:
            scheduling = tables_raw[key]['scheduling']
            self.schedulings.update([scheduling])
            use = tables_raw[key]['use']
            self.uses.update([use])
            os =  tables_raw[key]['os']
            self.oses.update([os])
            config_data = tables_raw[key]['config']
            self.currencies.update(config_data['currencies'])
            for region_data in config_data['regions']:
                region = self.instance_region_from_raw(region_data['region'])
                self.regions.update([region])
                if 'footnotes' in region_data:
                    self.footnotes[region] = region_data['footnotes']
                for instance_type_data in region_data['instanceTypes']:
                    instance_type = self.instance_types_from_raw(
                        instance_type_data['type'])
                    self.types.update([instance_type])
                    for size_data in instance_type_data['sizes']:
                        size = self.instance_size_from_raw(size_data['size'])
                        typesize = '%s.%s' % (instance_type, size)
                        if typesize not in self.typesizes:
                            self.typesizes[typesize] = set()
                        self.typesizes[typesize].update([region])
                        self.sizes.update([size])
                        for size_values in size_data['valueColumns']:
                            interval = size_values['name']
                            self.intervals.update([interval])
                            for currency in size_values['prices']:
                                cost = size_values['prices'][currency]
                                self.table_add_row(region, os, instance_type,
                                                   size, use, scheduling,
                                                   currency, cost)

    def table_add_row(self, region, os, instance_type, size, use, scheduling,
                      currency, cost):
        if cost == 'N/A*':
            return
        table = self.table
        for key in [region, os, instance_type, size, use, scheduling]:
            if key not in table:
                table[key] = {}
            table = table[key]
        table[currency] = cost

    def instance_region_from_raw(self, raw_region):
        '''Return a less intelligent given EC2 pricing name to the
        corresponding region name.
        '''
        regions = {
            'apac-tokyo' : 'ap-northeast-1',
            'apac-sin'   : 'ap-southeast-1',
            'eu-ireland' : 'eu-west-1',
            'sa-east-1'  : 'sa-east-1',
            'us-east'    : 'us-east-1',
            'us-west'    : 'us-west-1',
            'us-west-2'  : 'us-west-2',
            }
        return regions[raw_region] if raw_region in regions else raw_region

    def instance_types_from_raw(self, raw_type):
        types = {
            # ondemand                 reserved
            'stdODI'          : 'm1',  'stdResI'         : 'm1',
            'uODI'            : 't1',  'uResI'           : 't1',
            'hiMemODI'        : 'm2',  'hiMemResI'       : 'm2',
            'hiCPUODI'        : 'c1',  'hiCPUResI'       : 'c1',
            'clusterComputeI' : 'cc1', 'clusterCompResI' : 'cc1',
            'clusterGPUI'     : 'cc2', 'clusterGPUResI'  : 'cc2',
            'hiIoODI'         : 'hi1', 'hiIoResI'        : 'hi1'
            }
        return types[raw_type]

    def instance_size_from_raw(self, raw_size):
        sizes = {
            'u'         : 'micro',
            'sm'        : 'small',
            'med'       : 'medium',
            'lg'        : 'large',
            'xl'        : 'xlarge',
            'xxl'       : '2xlarge',
            'xxxxl'     : '4xlarge',
            'xxxxxxxxl' : '8xlarge'
            }
        return sizes[raw_size]

    def cost(self, region, os, instance_type, size, use, scheduling,
             currency):
        try:
            return self.table[region][os][instance_type][
                size][use][scheduling][currency]
        except KeyError as ex:
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another unsanctioned "api" which covers reserved instances: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/pricing-reserved-instances.json

Answer (score 0):

There is a [reply to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106403/535203) which lists all the `.js` files containing the prices, which are barely JSON files (with only a `callback(...);` statement to remove).

Here is an exemple for Linux On Demand prices : http://aws-assets-pricing-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/pricing/ec2/linux-od.js

(Get the full list [directly on that reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106403/535203))