# How to display aws ec2,rds price details in my java web application page

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ec2, aws-java-sdk

I am new in aws. i want display aws ec2 and rds price details in my website(developing at java spring).
Thanks,
SriRam.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: Hi Barny,   i saw api documentation class (com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.DescribeSpotPriceHistoryResult,PriceSchedule,SpotPrice..etc) . DescribeSpotPriceHistoryResult class get .json output, but i don't know how to do programmatic . please provide any ref, examples and sample code.

Comment: Its not clear what you ask, are you looking to build something like http://www.ec2instances.info/ to display EC2 price per instance (this is python code you can leverage), spot price, bid price to place bid; there are a lot of different prices so please be specific

Comment: "I am creating AWS instances programmatically  using AWS Java API. this entire process is developed as an web application. Now the question is, After successful purchase and instance of aws I need to display the price details of that particular customer's instance cost. Could some one help me please. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Henri, I am creating AWS instances programmatically  using AWS Java API. this entire process is developed as an web application. Now the question is, After successful purchase and instance of aws I need to display the price details of that particular customer's instance cost. how to get particular ec2 instance price details through java api Could some one help me please. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Henri, i got little bit solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636578/are-there-any-apis-for-amazon-web-services-pricing