# Is it possible to get pricing for AWS S3 programmatically through their SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to be able to estimate the cost of a download operation from S3 programmatically but I hesitate to hard-code the prices they list (per GB) on their pricing page in the event they change.  Does the SDK provide any kind of access to current pricing data. If it does, I can't seem to find it.

CLARIFICATION: I'm asking if the official Amazon SDK has hooks for pricing data, not if it's possible to get pricing data at all.  Obviously, it is possible to get pricing data through non-documented means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any API's for Amazon Web Services PRICING?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636578/are-there-any-apis-for-amazon-web-services-pricing)

Comment: @awendt No it's not a duplicate. I clearly asked if the SDK provided access to pricing data, not whether a clever SO member can figure out a way to do it.

Comment: @awendt And I have to add that while SO might reward this kind of tattling, it's really annoying to someone who has done their homework and is asking a legitimate question.  SO seems to breed nit-pickers that just focus on getting points rather than actually answering questions. You won't get a trophy for finding a vaguely similar question and then getting someone's question down-voted.  You just deny someone information they need.  Good for you.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. You see, I didn't down-vote your question (it's a perfectly fine question), and I don't get points for expressing the feeling that this is a duplicate. None of us get any points except for useful questions and answers which is a fair system. I did cast a vote to close your question but that doesn't mean anything as long as less than 4 other people feel the same way. That's why SO auto-comments "Possible duplicate of" – it's just one person's opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're asking for SDK support and SDKs are language-specific, I have to stress I can only speak for the **Ruby SDK**.

The Ruby SDK in the latest major version (2.x) is mostly auto-generated by an API description in JSON format [for each documented API](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/tree/master/aws-sdk-core/apis). There is no official pricing API – only a [static file](http://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/s3/pricing-storage-s3.min.js) that states:

> This file is intended for use only on aws.amazon.com. We do not guarantee its availability or accuracy.

This means there is no way for the Ruby SDK to give you pricing information. Your mileage may vary in other languages (but I doubt it).